# CSS not linking on Github

Tags: css, github

I've linked my css folder containing my `styles.css` file to my `index.html` like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

It works when I run it locally, but when I upload it to Github pages, the CSS does not seem to be linked.

The [link](https://baddusername.github.io/PV/) to my site, and my [repo](https://github.com/Baddusername/PV).

Answer (score 1):

You have spelling mistake in your `href` attribute where you are trying to link your css file. If you look closely, your folder where your `styles.css` is location is `CSS` not `css`!. Replace your link to stylesheet with the following line:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css">
```

Remember, file/folder names are *case-sensitive*.